# Roots of a polynomial with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, roots

Let $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2x^k$. Show that polynomial $f(x)$ has $n$ distinct real roots, for $n\ge2$. What I've tried: 
I tried to prove it by induction.
Let $P(n): f(x) = (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dots(x-\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\dots\alpha_n$ are the distinct real roots of polynomial. 
Suppose that $P(n)$ is true and show that $P(n+1)$ is also true.
$P(n+1):f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k}^2x^k$ 
Now I written $\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1}$ and thus
$$ f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1}\right)^2x^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n}{k}^2 + \binom{n}{k-1}^2 + 2\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}\right)x^k \\= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k}^2x^k + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}^2x^k+2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}x^k.$$ But what can I do now? I've tried several times but last term of this expression seems difficult to factorize.

Comment: Are you familiar with Legendre polynomials ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry, but no. If you can explain me the basics would be great. I've seen some posts on this forum that are related to my question that implies Legendre polynomials, such [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068330/sum-of-product-of-squared-binomial-coefficients) but i don't understand very much

Comment: Don't worry : you will learn about them quite soon. To make the story short (and similar to the linked post), if you let $x=\frac{t-1}{t+1}$, you have $\left(\frac{2}{t+1}\right)^n P_n(t)$ Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials

Comment: Have a look at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493672/asymptotic-behavior-of-local-maximum-minimum-points-of-the-legendre-polynomial/4493863#4493863

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks for all help! But are there other methods that do not involve Legendre polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica gives
$$f(x)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2x^k= (1-x)^n P_n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$
Where $P_n(z)$ are the well known Legendre Polynomials or order $n$ with distinct  real zeros $z_n$. So we will have roots $x_n$ of $f(x)=0$ as $$x_n=\frac{z_n-1}{z_n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks! But are there other methods that do not involve Legendre polynomials?

Comment: Yes it can be written in terms of Hypergeometric function, but the zeros of Pn(z) are well known in hand books and in computers  This is a big benefit.